# alternative approaches to selecting elements from two vectors conditional on a third

Tags: list-manipulation, core-language

The following will convey the idea: build a new vector based on an existing condition (boolean) vector. For simplicity, I'll build the conditioning vector (`cond`) in a known fashion.

```
(* setup: 3 vectors, one of which is boolean *)
init = RandomInteger[10, 10]
subs = RandomInteger[{11, 20}, 10]
cond = Thread[init > 5]
```

Here is one approach to building the desired vector:

```
MapThread[If, {cond, init, subs}]
```

Is this a good approach, speedwise? Am I overlooking a builtin?

Comment: try also `init + UnitStep[5 - init] (subs - init)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)" *)
```

kglr's solution is fast. The performance differences are very dramatic for larger lists

```
Manipulate[
 SeedRandom[1234];
 init = RandomInteger[10, n];
 subs = RandomInteger[{11, 20}, n];
 cond = Thread[init > 5];
 t1 = RepeatedTiming[sol1 = (* Alan *)
      MapThread[If[#1, #2, #3] &, {cond, init, subs}];][[1]];
 t2 = RepeatedTiming[sol2 = (* Hanlon *)
      If @@@ Thread[{cond, init, subs}];][[1]];
 t3 = RepeatedTiming[sol3 =(* kglr *)
      init + UnitStep[5 - init] (subs - init);][[1]];
 Grid[
  Prepend[{{sol1 === sol2 === sol3, t1/t3, t2/t3}},
   {"Equal", "t1/t3", "t2/t3"}],
  Frame -> All],
 {{n, 10}, 10^Range[5]}]
```

[image]

Comment: With the larger vectors the speed difference is startling.